# fish.config doesn't get loaded on new tab in TotalTerminal on OSX

Tags: macos, fish

I want to add Android SDK tools to my $PATH variable. I've entered the following to ~/.config/fish/config.fish:

`set -x PATH $PWD/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/tools $PATH`

`set -x PATH $PWD/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools $PATH`

It works in the initial window when I start TotalTerminal, but when I open another tab (with Cmd+T), the path is not set, as if config.fish is not loaded when I open another tab. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Replace `$PWD` with `$HOME` so that fish will look for the android tools relative to your homefolder instead of the current folder you're browsing. Correct lines should therefore be:

```
set -x PATH $HOME/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/tools $PATH
set -x PATH $HOME/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools $PATH
```

You could also declare the scope to be global by adding a `g` to the `-x` parameter.

For more info on the syntax for `set`, please look at the fish man-page: http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/user_doc/html/commands.html#set